# Errors when adding firebase to a project that calls Microsoft graph

Tags: android, firebase, dependencies, build.gradle, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to add firebase to a existing application which involves adding:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
```

as dependency to the project level build.gradle, and adding:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

as a plugin to the app level build.gradle.

The project that I am building upon is "Sign users in/out and call the Microsoft Graph from an Android app"

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-android

Project level build.gradle

```java
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    apply from: rootProject.file("gradle/versions.gradle")

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:$rootProject.ext.gradleVersion"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

App level build.gradle

```java
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        google()
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            name "vsts-maven-adal-android"
            url "https://identitydivision.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/AndroidADAL/maven/v1"
            credentials {
                username System.getenv("ENV_VSTS_MVN_ANDROIDADAL_USERNAME") != null ? System.getenv("ENV_VSTS_MVN_ANDROIDADAL_USERNAME") : project.findProperty("vstsUsername")
                password System.getenv("ENV_VSTS_MVN_ANDROIDADAL_ACCESSTOKEN") != null ? System.getenv("ENV_VSTS_MVN_ANDROIDADAL_ACCESSTOKEN") : project.findProperty("vstsMavenAccessToken")
            }
        }
        jcenter()
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "[com.*.*]"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file("../gradle/debug.keystore")
            storePassword 'android'
            keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
            keyPassword 'android'
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    flavorDimensions "main"
    productFlavors {
        local {
            // To be used with android-complete only.

            // So that it could look for the 'local' flavor in Broker projects.
            matchingFallbacks = ['local']
        }

        external {}
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:$rootProject.ext.appCompatVersion"
    implementation "com.google.android.material:material:$rootProject.ext.materialVersion"
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'

    if (findProject(':msal') != null) {
        // For developer team only.
        localImplementation project(':msal')
        externalImplementation 'com.microsoft.identity.client:msal:1.0.+'
    } else {
        // Downloads and Builds MSAL from maven central.
        implementation 'com.microsoft.identity.client:msal:1.0.+'
    }

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Below is versions.gradle

```java
// Variables for entire project
ext {
    // SDK
    minSdkVersion = 16
    automationAppMinSDKVersion = 21
    targetSdkVersion = 27
    compileSdkVersion = 28
    buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"

    // Plugins
    gradleVersion = '3.2.1'
    androidMavenGradlePluginVersion = "1.4.1"

    // Libraries
    annotationVersion = "1.0.0"
    appCompatVersion = "1.0.2"
    browserVersion = "1.0.0"
    dexmakerMockitoVersion = "1.4"
    espressoCoreVersion = "3.1.0"
    gsonVersion = "2.8.5"
    junitVersion = "4.12"
    legacySupportV4Version = "1.0.0"
    localBroadcastManagerVersion = "1.0.0"
    materialVersion = "1.0.0"
    mockitoCoreVersion = "2.18.3"
    mockitoAndroidVersion = "2.18.3"
    multidexVersion = "2.0.1"
    powerMockVersion = "1.6.6"
    nimbusVersion = "5.7"
    runnerVersion = "1.2.0"
    rulesVersion = "1.2.0"

    // TODO: adal automation test app.
    supportLibraryVersion = "27.1.+"
    adalLegacy = "1.15.0"
}
```

Error when syncing project

```java
org.gradle.api.ProjectConfigurationException: A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleScriptException: A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: ASCII
    at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.checkPathForErrors(BasePlugin.java:1006)
    at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.apply(BasePlugin.java:261)
    at com.android.build.gradle.AbstractAppPlugin.apply(AbstractAppPlugin.java:122)
    at com.android.build.gradle.AppPlugin.apply(AppPlugin.java:43)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I was able to solve it by using classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.0' instead of classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'. Build this to see another type of error. Then do invalidate cache and restart on Android studio from the File menu. Then on restart, your build should be successful. You might also need to use 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:16.0.0' instead of the current version